# Making nav menu sticky and transparent

Tags: menus, css

I am currently having a hard time making it real. I am using a custom theme but there are no settings for the things i'm searching for. Now the header is transparent but not sticky. I want to make it sticky with a dark color and a little opacity with a bottom border and shadow. Moreover, i would also want to make it shrink. For the time i've spent i think editing the theme's files is my only solution so i need help for the code itself.
Here's the site im testing on: https://www.dailylifehelper.com/home-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 .nav-class{position:fixed;} that will make navbar sticky
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Now that it is sticky i have to add the shrink effect and a low opacity background. However, i wasnt able to deal with that

Comment: add following in your js                                                                $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".nav-class").addClass("active");
    } else {
        
       $(".nav-class").removeClass("active");
    }
});

in your css
.active{
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

Comment: I couldnt make it work. I tried adding the js to several of my js files and also directly in the header. Can you be more specific? i think i might have messed up somewhere

Comment: Can you please share code of js and css?

Comment: style.css - https://pastebin.com/q5Qwf29y
js - https://pastebin.com/A03bj9ab ;
https://pastebin.com/6hDe8etM ;
https://pastebin.com/A5SuRZep